# DIV float right not working. What is wrong?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to float the timer right top across from the logo. but it's not working. 
If I use the regular `style="float:right"` it works perfect...

```
<div id="whole_page" />

            <div id="header" />
            <?php echo "$logo" ?>   
            <div id="timer" style="float:right" /><?php

            echo "$today"; 
            ?></div>
            </div>
            <div id="nav" />
            Home | 
            About | 
            Help
            </div>
            <div id="content" />
            <?php
            echo "Hello, my name is, $first_name \"$nick_name\" $last_name<br />";
            echo "I am from $city, $country<br />";
            ?>
            </div>
      </div>
```

This is the css:

```
#whole_page {
    width:          65em;
    margin:         auto;
    padding:        0;
    text-align:     left;
    border-width:   0 1px 1px;
    border-color:   #000;
    border-styler:  solid;
}

#header {
    color:          white;
    background:     #ebebeb;
    font-size:      24pt;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    font-weight:    bold;
}

#timer {
    float:          right;
    margin-bottom:  0;
}

#nav {
    color:          #000;
    font-size:      12pt;
    font-weight:    none;
    background:     #ebebeb;
    padding:        0.5em;
    border:         none;
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually, for a `float` to work, you need to set a `width` on the element.

(Otherwise, the browser renders the element at `100%` and there is nothing to float.)

So make this

```
#timer{
    width:200px; //OR WHATEVER SIZE
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use F12 debug? Do you see any style applied to the element? Also view the source code of of rendered page and see the actual CSS in the page. Then please post the necessary css from there to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to `div` header:

```
float:left;
```

If you want that a `div` to be in the next line just place:

```
clear: both;
```